# Where are my posts linked to? I keep getting a Not Found Error, and I have no single.php page

Tags: posts, loop, pages

Recently I had someone customize a WP blog for me. This person didn't do a very will job so I decided to do it myself. I customized my own blog page and it all works, except for when I click on the posts I get a "Not Found Error" page. I looked through the old blog that some person made and I can't tell where that person linked my posts to. The only clue I have is this bit of code after the `<?php the_content(); ?>`:

```
<?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-link">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentyten' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
```

I left this bit of code out when I customized my own page. Now I Get a "Not Found Error" when I click on the Post, here is my blog page:

```
    <?php
/*
Template Name: Blog
*/
?>

<?php get_header(); ?>

<br/>

<br/>

<section id="content">

  <div class="main">

    <div class="inner">

      <h3 class="h3 bg-3">Web   Design   inspiration,  all   resources  you   could   need !</h3>

    </div>

  </div>

  <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

  <?php query_posts('posts_per_page=3'); ?>

  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

  <div class="main">

    <div class="cycle">

      <div id="slider3" class="pics">

        <div class="box">

          <article>

            <figure class="box-img img-indent"><a class="lightbox-image box-image" data-gal="prettyPhoto" href="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" alt="" /></a></figure>

            <div class="inner"><a class="link-1" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Go to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>

              <div class="txt-3"><strong>Posted on:</strong> <span><?php the_time('m/d/y') ?></span></div>

              <p class="p3"><?php the_content() ?>
              </p>

            </div>

            <div class="clear"></div>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
          </article>



        </div>

      </div>

    </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div class="navigate2">

      <div id="nav"></div>

      <?php next_posts_link('<span id="next_slide2"> </span>') ?></div>

  </div>

  <?php else : ?>
<h2 class="center">Not Found</h2>
<p class="center">Sorry, but you are looking for something that isn't here.</p>
<?php endif; ?>

</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thanks in advance! (P.S. I'm working in my local host so I don't have a webpage that you can go to.)

Comment: Could you please show us the url that one of the broken links' sends you to, and what the url should be for the post you expected to be sent to? Also, is it this line of code that is generating the link you are clicking on? <div class="inner"><a class="link-1" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Go to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><br>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you included in your question is a *custom page template*, and would never be used by WordPress to render the single-post view of a blog post.

If you don't have a `single.php`, then [the template hierarchy will fall back to `index.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) to render the single-post view for blog posts.

#### Edit

From your comment below:

> I'm sorry. I need my **Posts** to link to an **individual [page]**. I do not know how to do that. I thought WP automatically linked my **posts** to a page called **single.php**. I would like to know how to do that.

Please have a read through [the **Template Hierarchy** Codex entry](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), which explains everything for you. I repeat my answer above: **If your Theme doesn't have a `single.php`, then [the template hierarchy will fall back to `index.php`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy#Single_Post_display) to render the single-post view for blog posts.**

Those are the only two possible template files for WordPress to use to render the single-post view of a blog post.

Regarding this comment:

> I don't know how to make my Permalinks link to a single.php page, I don't want them linked back to the index.php page.

I don't think you fully grasp how WordPress uses its template files. The `index.php` file isn't a "page", but rather a *template*, used to output a given *query*. Your Theme could consist of no other template file than `index.php`, and the site will render perfectly fine, and as intended/expected. WordPress will simply use the *template* to define the *markup* used to render the *data* in the given *query*.

If that query is the blog posts index, then WordPress will use it to render all of the posts for the blog posts index. If that query is an archive index, then WordPress will use it to render all of the posts in the specified archive. If that query is a **single blog post**, then WordPress will use that template to **render a single blog post**.

So: is there any **particular reason** you don't want your Theme to fall back to the `index.php` *template file* to render single blog posts?

Comment: Yes '<a class="link-1" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="Go to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>' Is what I want linking. I don't know how to make my Permalinks link to a single.php page, I don't want them linked back to the index.php page. How can I go about linking all my blog posts to a single.php page? I just want to customize my single.php page so that the posts show up on that page when people click on the permalinks.

Comment: Forget the template files for a moment. Just describe in **human terms** what you want to do? Because your comment above doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: I'm sorry. I need my **Posts** to link to an **individual**. I do not know how to do that. I thought WP automatically linked my **posts** to a page called **single.php**. I would like to know how to do that.

Comment: individual *page

Comment: Thank you for helping me Chip. How can I change the way the **rendered single blog posts** look? And how can I make the links work? When I click the links I get an _Error_ that states: **Not Found
The requested URL /ChristianInternetDesign/blog/2012/08/what-in-the-world/ was not found on this server.**

Comment: Okay, I am so sorry, I am pretty new to this. Went into the WP admin and changed the permalink settings to default and now I am not getting an _Error_. I also added a single.php template and the single blog posts are showing up on there. How can I change the permalinks to something other than the default and have them still work?

Comment: Permalink settings (i.e. rewrite rules and pretty permalinks) and the template hierarchy (i.e. which Theme template file is used to render a given query) have nothing to do with each other. Can you please clarify your question to indicate what you're ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have figured out _my problem_. I **answered** my own question. Thank you for your time and help, I am sorry I bothered you. I do not have any other question, I will look **somewhere else** for the help that I need. Do you need me to clarify that?

Comment: I'm glad you answered your question. Would you please **post it here as an answer**, so that others may benefit from it?